# Nant: instruct MySql to create db and run scripts

Tags: .net, mysql, build-process, build, nant

How do I instruct Nant to tell MySql to run ddl scripts from a particular location and then run other scripts as instructed?

Google let me to [many sites](http://www.google.co.in/search?q=nant+mysql) which unfortunately do not work...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use a nant script to recreate mysql stored procedures from files stored on a "procedures" folder. My Nant target looks like:

```
<target name="migrate-storeds" description="Creates stored procedures">
    <echo message="Creating Stored Procedures"/>
    <foreach item="File" property="filename">
    <in>
        <items>
            <include name="procedures\*.sql"></include>
        </items>
    </in>
    <do>
        <echo message="filename ${filename}"/>
        <exec program="${mysql.path}\mysql"
            workingdir="."
            failonerror="true"
            commandline='--host=${database.server} --user=${database.user} --password=${database.pwd} ${database.name} -e "source ${filename}"'/>
    </do>
    </foreach>
    <echo message="Procedures created succesfully"/>
</target>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to run scripts ddl against MySql using [the `<sql>` task](http://nantcontrib.sourceforge.net/release/0.85-rc1/help/tasks/sql.html) in the NAntContrib project. `<sql>` requires an OLEDB connection, and [as far as I can tell](http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql#p27) MySql supports this.