# Cruise Control .NET - database schema migration

Tags: .net, continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net

We have next:

- Big solution with a lot of changes to db
- Production database (is the master referance database
- Local db for each devs
- Changescripts commit (changes to master referance database)
- Folder with changes to database: sql files list like 010.SomeFeatue.sql, 020.SomeFeature.sql
- Mysql

What we need:
On each and every commit of new sql files we need to:

- Back test database to master dump
- apply all change scripts from first to last
- have a log of scripts was runned
- Have a status seccess/fail for each script

Any idea? Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CruiseControl.NET has good integration with [Nant](http://nant.sourceforge.net/), which is much better than CCNET at general scripting for your build.  If it were me, I would use Nant to reload your test db, and  to apply to the changes.  It will also allow you to check the status of each script.  Logging is integrated with CCNET automatically.

Comment: like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2778922/nant-instruct-mysql-to-create-db-and-run-scripts ?